# How can I take specific column in factor variable?

Tags: r, factors

I have a corona data and the dates column is a factor variable. I want to take just may month. I know I can take it from counting the rows but I want to do it with the date column.

This is how I tried:

```r
spndata <- data[data$iso_code == "ESP" & as.numeric(2020-05-01) < data$date < as.numeric(2020-06-01),]
```

dates are in Year/Month/Day order.
Thanks.

`class = "factor"), date = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2019-12-31", 
    "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", 
    "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10", 
    "2020-01-11", "2020-01-12", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-15", 
    "2020-01-16", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-18", "2020-01-19", "2020-01-20", 
    "2020-01-21", "2020-01-22", "2020-01-23", "2020-01-24", "2020-01-25", 
    "2020-01-26", "2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", "2020-01-30", 
    "2020-01-31", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", 
    "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-07", "2020-02-08", "2020-02-09", 
    "2020-02-10", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", 
    "2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", 
    "2020-02-20", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23", "2020-02-24", 
    "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", 
    "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", 
    "2020-03-06", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", 
    "2020-03-11", "2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", 
    "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", 
    "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", 
    "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", "2020-03-30", 
    "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-03", "2020-04-04", 
    "2020-04-05", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-09", 
    "2020-04-10", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", 
    "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19", 
    "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", 
    "2020-04-25", "2020-04-26", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", 
    "2020-04-30", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", 
    "2020-05-05", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", 
    "2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", 
    "2020-05-15", "2020-05-16", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", 
    "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-23", "2020-05-24", 
    "2020-05-25", "2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29", 
    "2020-05-30", "2020-05-31", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", 
    "2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-07", "2020-06-08", 
    "2020-06-09", "2020-06-10", "2020-06-11", "2020-06-12", "2020-06-13", 
    "2020-06-14", "2020-06-15")`

Comment: It seems you forget to quote your date values. `as.numeric("2020-05-01")` or `as.Date("2020-05-01", "%Y-%M-%D")`

Comment: yes I forgot to add

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you make a *reproducible example* of your data - the best way would be something like `dput(head(data))` and paste the output into your post.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Make sure the `date` variable's `class` is `Date`.  If it isn't, change it to date via `as.Date()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `date` is a date class or coercible to date, this should work.

```
spndata <- data[data$iso_code == "ESP" & data$date > as.Date("2020-05-01") &  data$date < as.Date("2020-06-01"),]
```

Comment: Can you add a small example of your data in the post so that I can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Make sure the `date` variable's `class` is `Date`.  If it isn't, change it to date via `as.Date()` function.